# React prop not being passed to component during .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've fetched an array of news articles from an api which is in the newsArticles state.

I map over the state and deconstruct the data that I need. I then pass the title and description props to the card. Then I've got a modal that's hidden using CSS and I pass the title and content prop to the modal.

My problem is that when I open the modal, the correct title and content isn't displaying. Regardless which article I click on, when I open the modal it only displays the title and content of the last article in the array. It should display the correct title and content for the card that has been cliced on.

Why is this happening? My code is below. Thanks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNewsContext } from '../context/news-context';

const NewsCard = () => {
  const { newsArticles, isLoading } = useNewsContext();
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const readMore = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeBtn = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <section className='news-section wrapper'>
      {' '}
      {newsArticles.map((item, index) => {
        const { title, description, urlToImage, content } = item;

        return (
          <div key={index} className='news-card'>
            <img className='news-image' src={urlToImage} alt={title} /> <h1> {title} </h1>{' '}
            <p> {description} </p>{' '}
            <button type='button' onClick={readMore}>
              {' '}
              Read More{' '}
            </button>{' '}
            <div className={isModalOpen ? 'news-modal' : 'news-modal news-modal__hidden'}>
              <div className='news-modal__card'>
                <h1> {title} </h1> <p> {content} </p>{' '}
                <button type='button' onClick={closeBtn}>
                  {' '}
                  Close{' '}
                </button>
              </div>{' '}
            </div>{' '}
          </div>
        );
      })}{' '}
    </section>
  );
};

export default NewsCard;
```

Comment: You have multiple modals, one for each mapped element and only a single `show` trigger.  When `modalOpen` is true, all modals are shown, and the last rendered is on top, so the last one in the array. You'll need to track which modal you want to open. This is a good time to refactor the mapped JSX to a new component and have each manage its own modal logic.

Comment: Would it be easier to use url params and just create a new page component?